# Disk space reducing script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Reducing disk space on automation method using unix command.

Rules:

1.directly go to 2 path on d1 directory. Then, only need to select zipped log files older than 5 days of that 2 paths.

I have tried below find command and it's resolved my issue, but I don't need to use find command to finding path and reduce space. Can anyone say another command will solve this issue.

Find ./var/log -name ".log.gz" -print

Find. /var/log -name ".log.gz" -type f -mtime +5  -exec rm -f {} ;

Comment: Have you tried `logrotate`?  Might also be better to ask this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Write `Find` in lowercase (as `find`), remove the first dot. When you want to remove `*.log.gz`, use `"*.log.gz"` or `\*.log.gz`.

Comment: BTW, if you only need to support GNU find, you can use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm ...`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to use this find command any other way like using loops for getting this details. I mean what I used and getting output on  above find cmd, that I need to configure in .sh file.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
find /var/log -name '*.log.gz' -type f -mtime +5 -exec rm -f {} +
```

`-name` expects a glob, not a suffix. Put it in single-quotes so the shell doesn't try to expand it.

`-exec command {} \;` runs the given command once for each found file, which is a problem if you have, say, 50,000 files to delete. Terminating with `+` instead causes the command to be run as few times as possible, with as many found files as possible passed as command line arguments.

Comment: `-exec rm -f {} +`  (with a `+` in place of a `\;` in terminal position) gives you the same performance enhancement `xargs` provides, without the extra overhead of spinning up an external xargs executable. It's only the `-exec rm -f {} \;` form that runs one `rm` per file.

Comment: (...and it's not a GNUism, either -- the form has been POSIX-standardized since 2007/2008 or therebouts; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).

Comment: Hey that's awesome! To be fair I've been doing it with xargs since way before 2007, I never noticed that the support for + had been added. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Actually, above command it's working for me. That output need to configure on .sh file. Like using loops or any other method.